# Getting user error when trying a web request

Tags: json, vimeo

I am making the following request trying to get the thumbnail images for a specific video.

```
https://api.vimeo.com/videos/447593888/pictures?access_token=XXXXXXXXXX
```

I generated the access token in my account however I get the following error.

"No user credentials were provided."

Any idea why this wouldn't work? I wish there was a simple send and return the Title, Duration, Thumbnail when I sent the ID value.

Comment: did you do all the steps here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access tokens should be passed in the request header, not as a query parameter (this is also insecure as a malicious actor could intercept the request url and get your access token, which is why only tokens with "public" scope can be provided this way): https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#presenting-the-access-token

> I wish there was a simple send and return the Title, Duration, Thumbnail when I sent the ID value.

Have you tried oEmbed? The oEmbed API doesn't require authentication, and can be used to get the metadata (name, description, thumbnails) for any embeddable video: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos

Comment: That is exactly what I needed Tommy thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Tommy any idea how to use oEmbed when your video is set to no embed? When I do that it blocks all the information I need.

Comment: @TimStrathman If it's not embeddable (embed privacy is set to "nowhere"), then it cannot be "read" by oEmbed. To get its metadata, you'll need to use the full-fledged core API: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo oEmbed works perfectly and you can send in the height/width of the thumbnail you want and it pulls that, duration, title, desc, created date, etc.  Awesome!